# Как настроить nginx для двух папок в разных директориях

Tags: nginx

Есть проект на Laravel.  Структура папок следующая.

```
/var/www/frontend/web - тут фронт
/var/www/backend/web/ - тут админка.
```

Для фронта всё работает отлично, но для бека проблемы. Выдает 404

```
server_name xxx.ru www.xxx.ru;
root        /var/www/frontend/web;
index       index.php;


location / {
    index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /odmin {
alias /var/www/backend/web/;

}
```

Подскажите что не так

Comment: Читайте в логах nginx, по какой причине он решил выдать 404

Comment: @Radzhab выложите логи. Визуально всё, вроде, правильно, если нет орфографических ошибок типа odmin. Полагаю так задумано.